# Heroku timezone on logs doesn't change though TZ was changed

Tags: heroku

I use Heroku and want to see logs in the JST timezone, not the UTC.
So I changed the TZ variable on Heroku CLI and checked the JST works by running date command on Heroku bash, but Heroku logs seem to be shown in the UTC.
Are there any solutions to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume by changing the `TZ` environment, you mean setting `TZ` on the Dyno. This won't affect logs, as your logs could have many sources (Postgres, Redis etc...). Generally, it's always best to keep all of your services running in UTC, as this will keep debugging across systems easier. If you need to convert your logs to JST for analysis, I recommend setting up a logging add-on like papertrail, this will allow you to view logs in your preferred timezone, while keeping the main log stream in UTC.